# Excel formulas linked to other workbooks don't update automatically (without opening the source)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel formulas linked to other workbooks don't update automatically (without opening the source), but when I open the source workbook it automatically updates itself.

Is it possible to get the data updated without opening the source workbook?

Answer (score 3):

When you create external references (also called links), you can control whether the external references stay up to date, and when they are updated. If another user has changed a value in a cell, Microsoft Office Excel does not look for the new value unless you tell it to.

To update the links, on the Trust Bar, click Options, and then click Enable this Content.

[this document has full details](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-HP010102348.aspx?CTT=3) for more you could want to do

- Learn more about external references
- Control links to other workbooks
- Manually update all of the links or none of the links in a workbook
- Manually update only some of the links to other workbooks Control the
- startup prompt for updating all of the links Don't ask whether to
- update links when I open any workbook, and update links automatically
- Don't ask to update links for this workbook, and let me control
  whether links are updated
- Decide whether to update links when
  prompted at startup