# R: closing a csv file from within R

Tags: r, csv

I can open a csv file from within R:

```
 shell.exec("test.csv")
```

But how to I close a csv file from within R?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You would have to use `taskkill` somehow from R, or possibly a package if one exists for that.  In general though why would you want to close the viewer from within R?

Comment: I need to have the file closed when I update it from R. I then need to have it open so that it links to an excel workbook as the links do not work if it is closed (I have tried all the suggestions without success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697703/excel-formulas-linked-to-other-workbooks-doesnt-update-automatically-without-o).

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-87861952-ca9d-4d2a-a986-4d672c908d0d?CTT=3&CorrelationId=83d5fe22-d855-4d80-a081-4a7394d753fd&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US